# jenkins archive artifacts - what's the format?

Tags: jenkins, archive

I can't seem to figure out how to use the basic archive artifacts statement. What I want is to archive an entire subtree but naming it doesn't seem to work. Nor does `directory/**` nor `directory/**/`

I've read the ant doc but it doesn't make much sense to me.

How do I specify a subtree?  Or... where can I find a meaningful description of whatever goes in that field?

Answer (score 100, accepted):

Directory/**/*.* -> All the files recursively under Directory

**/*.* -> all the files in the workspace

**/*.xml -> all xml files in your workspace.

Directory/**/*.xml -> All the xml files recursively under Directory

Comment: Thank you.  Why the extra period?

Comment: ** represent a folders hierarchy, but *.* represents the files you want to archive. you need to specify which files, and not folders, you need to archive

Comment: If it worked for you can you please mark it as the right answer? Thanks! :)

Comment: For the files recursively under Directory option how does it treat subfolders that hold files with the same name?

Comment: It's sufficient to use `*` to denote files, that is: `Directory/**/*`.

Comment: How to include a folder?

Comment: @Prem to include a folder, you have to include the files in the folder. e.g. `directory/**/*`.

Comment: @yktoo it depends on the Jenkins version, a lot have changed since ;)

Answer (score 0):

Example:

archiveArtifacts 'test-results//**, dir1//dir2/**/*'